# Finding serial number of USB drive without WMI

Tags: c#

How do we find the serial number of a USB drive without using WMI in c#?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use WMI? It would appear that trying to get the serial number without WMI may give you the volatile (changed when fromated) serial number.

Comment: I've had issues with WMI in some pc's occasionally. Sometimes,the WMI service gets closed with a "Don't send" or "Close Program". I really wish we would not have to depend on that service.

Comment: And, WMI can be significantly slower than directly hitting the Windows API. I discovered this trying to enumerate USB devices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following link looks like a good place to start if you can use WMI. [Volatile USB Serial Number Using C#](http://www.cfdan.com/posts/Retrieving_Non-Volatile_USB_Serial_Number_Using_C_Sharp.cfm).

You could implement a WMI soloution as this looks like it is pretty simple code and has been fairly extensivly tested. If you get a WMI error you could gracefully fall into another implementation using non WMI calls.

To get the serial number without using WMI I would recommend that you look at the microsoft scripting runtime. You can add this to your project references from the COM tab.

Comment: Why down vote? Op hasn't answered why he doesn't want to use WMI, so no reason to down vote.

Comment: yep ,I totally agree...I don't know who down voted...
I've up voted it again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that C# has any native APIs for that sort of thing, but [this blog post](http://addressof.com/blog/archive/2004/02/14/392.aspx) suggests a way to do it with interop.  Code is in VB.net, but it shouldn't be too hard to translate into c#  Hope that helps.

Comment: But that link does not provide a function to get USB drive's serial number as far as I know. It's only getting me the serial number of fixed disks.