# Get a Unique ID for a Hard disk attached to a PC in .net

Tags: .net, winforms

As the question states I need some way of getting a unique ID for each of the drives attached to my PC.

The reason behind this is that if i store the location of a file in a DB and I want to retrieve it at a later stage I wont always get the file since the drive letters change depending on the number of drives plugged in.

Comment: check this link [Get Volume Serial Number in C#](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20021019.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Each harddisk/storage device has a serial number.

You need to query that value: [Read USB Device Serial number in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176053/read-usb-device-serial-number-in-c)

Comment: This is correct, but you probably don't need a hardware ID for this application.  A volume serial number should be sufficient for locating a specific file.