# How do I detect a USB drive letter from a c# application?

Tags: c#, usb

How to detect the USB drive letter from c# program which is not residing in the USB? The program should reside in the system, if multiple USB's are connected then i should first able to get the manufacturer name also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will get all of the removable drives attached (including USB drives):

```
foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
    if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
    {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Getting the USB drive manufacturer may be more difficult, and you may need to use WMI.

**Edit**: Here are 2 links on reading USB drive information:

- [how to determine USB Flash drive manufacturer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123986/how-to-determine-usb-flash-drive-manufacturer)
- [Finding serial number of USB drive without WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777569/finding-serial-number-of-usb-drive-without-wmi)

Comment: Some USB drive may not be detected

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> list_usb= DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(d => d.DriveType.ToString() == "Removable").Select(d => d.Name).ToList();

            foreach(var i in list_usb)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
```

you can try this.