# C# Checking for presence of usb drive

Tags: c#

I am writing a file that extracts xml to obtain name of files and need to copy these files to the USB drive. The first 2 steps I able to do this. But questions is:

1. How can I detect if there is a USB Drive
2. Then detect which drive it is.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I detect a USB drive letter from a c# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273872/how-do-i-detect-a-usb-drive-letter-from-a-c-application)

Comment: are you writing a virus?

Answer (score 5):

This code goes in the other direction, but it handles the "how do I find a USB drive" question:

```
 using System.IO;
```

// . . .

```
        foreach (DriveInfo removableDrive in DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(
            d => d.DriveType == DriveType.Removable && d.IsReady))
        {
            DirectoryInfo rootDirectory = removableDrive.RootDirectory;
            string monitoredDirectory = Path.Combine(rootDirectory.FullName, DIRECTORY_TO_MONITOR);
            string localDestDirectory = Path.Combine(destDirectory, removableDrive.VolumeLabel);
            if (!Directory.Exists(localDestDirectory))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(localDestDirectory);
            if (Directory.Exists(monitoredDirectory))
            {
                foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(monitoredDirectory))
                {
                    File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(localDestDirectory, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `DriveInfo.GetDrives()` for `DriveType.Removeable` property
then check `FullName`